# Grouping with partition and over in TSql

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by, window-functions, rowcount

I have a simple table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tooling](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Status] [int] NOT NULL,
[DateFinished] [datetime] NULL,
[Tooling] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Updated] [datetime] NULL,

 ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

with following values

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Tooling] ON 

GO
INSERT [dbo].[Tooling] ([Id], [Name], [Status], [DateFinished], [Tooling], [Updated]) VALUES (1, N'Large', 0, NULL, NULL, CAST(N'2015-05-05 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Tooling] ([Id], [Name], [Status], [DateFinished], [Tooling], [Updated]) VALUES (2, N'Large', 1, NULL, N'1', CAST(N'2015-05-10 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Tooling] ([Id], [Name], [Status], [DateFinished], [Tooling], [Updated]) VALUES (3, N'Small', 0, NULL, N'2', CAST(N'2015-05-11 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Tooling] ([Id], [Name], [Status], [DateFinished], [Tooling], [Updated]) VALUES (4, N'Large', 2, NULL, N'1', CAST(N'2015-05-12 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Tooling] ([Id], [Name], [Status], [DateFinished], [Tooling], [Updated]) VALUES (5, N'Large', 2, NULL, N'2', CAST(N'2015-05-12 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Tooling] ([Id], [Name], [Status], [DateFinished], [Tooling], [Updated]) VALUES (6, N'Large', 1, NULL, N'1', CAST(N'2015-05-13 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Tooling] ([Id], [Name], [Status], [DateFinished], [Tooling], [Updated]) VALUES (7, N'Large', 1, NULL, N'2', CAST(N'2015-05-14 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Tooling] ([Id], [Name], [Status], [DateFinished], [Tooling], [Updated]) VALUES (8, N'Small', 1, CAST(N'2015-05-15 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'2', CAST(N'2015-05-15 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Tooling] OFF
```

I want to create a view of the table that looks like its an entirely own table.

```
SELECT         Id, Name, Status, DateFinished
FROM          Tooling t order by t.id
```

If i run that I would like that the records with id 5 and 7 should be excluded since they dont change in the selected set from the previous row.
I had an idea to solve this by using,  ROW_NUMBER() over partition 
And by using group by but thats seems to incorrect(Could not to get it to work at all)

How do I group it when the should be grouped on that the value change and not the value it contains?
Any suggestions to solve this? 
My end goal is also try to convert this to linq to entities...

Comment: Id is definetly different by design. Do you mean `Name, Status, DateFinished` are not changed? You also need to define the order - by id or what?

Comment: Thats correct. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, supposing it's ordered by id

```
select * 
from (
  select *, rng = row_number() over (partition by grp order by id)
  from (
    select *, grp = row_number() over (order by id) - row_number() over (partition by Name, Status, DateFinished order by id)
    from tooling ) g
  ) gn
where rng = 1
order by id
```

Comment: Really nice. Did exactly what I wanted,

Comment: Note you've got it quckly, and that's totally your merit. The question containing sample data script is pleasure to answer.